# Passing the same object from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton

I have a Mainactivity that contains the list of Trainings. And on each list is clicked it starts the session of the same training in whole application.
I managed to use Singleton and access that into my main activity. But onItemClick it takes to dialog box and on button click inside dialog it should take to another activity. Now I a getting error like java NullPointerException. Here is the code below;
Remember: I want same training session in second activity also.

MainActivity class;

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    currentTraining = (Training)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

    Log.i("DEBUG", currentTraining.getTitle());

    CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);

    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "You clicked on position : " + arg2 + " and ID : "
                    + currentTraining.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    dialog.setTitle(currentTraining.getTitle());

    TextView description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    description.setText("Description: " + currentTraining.getDescription());

    TextView location = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    location.setText("Location: " + currentTraining.getLocation());

    TextView date = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    date.setText("Date: " + currentTraining.getDate());

    Button back_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    Button start_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    start_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    TraineeActivity.class);

            //intent.putExtra("trainingId", currentTraining.getId());

            //intent.putExtra("title", currentTraining.getTitle().toString());

            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

And in second Activity Class;

```
Training currentTraining;

private ListView personNamesListView;

// Adapter to made the connection between ListView UI component and SQLite  data set.
private ListAdapter traineeListAdapter;

private TextView TitleView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trainees);

    currentTraining = CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);
    Log.i("DEBUG", ""+currentTraining.getTitle());

    TitleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.training_title);
    TitleView.setText(currentTraining.getTitle());

    Button addnew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TraineeActivity.this,
                    FormActivity.class);
            TraineeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    personNamesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.traineeslist);

    // Create a list that contains only full name of the trainee
    traineeListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trainee>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currentTraining.getTraineeArrayList());
    personNamesListView.setAdapter(traineeListAdapter);

}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    traineeListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trainee>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currentTraining.getTraineeArrayList());
    personNamesListView.setAdapter(traineeListAdapter);

}
```

My Singleton Class:

```
public class CurrentTraining {

private Training training ; //Training is my model class

private static CurrentTraining instance;

private CurrentTraining() {

}

public static CurrentTraining getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CurrentTraining();
    return instance;

}

public Training getTraining() {
    return training;
}

public Training setTraining(Training training) {
    return this.training = training;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` of your second activity, you do this:

```
currentTraining = CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);
```

Since `currentTraining` is `null`, this will just set the singleton variable `training` to `null` and return `null`.

Where are you actually setting the value of the one that the user picked?